# Not sure how to call function within useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to call a function ('setLoading()') within useEffect. However, for some reason, the function will not mount. I think there's an error in the way i am calling this function within useEffect.

Below is how I have tried to call it-

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading();
  console.log('abcd');
  CognitensorEndpoints.getDashboardList({
    dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
  });
  CognitensorEndpoints.getList({
    dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
  });
}, []);
```

Here's the full app code-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Keyboard, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../theme';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { apiStateReducer } from '../reducers/ApiStateReducer';
import CognitensorEndpoints from '../services/network/CognitensorEndpoints';
import DefaultView from '../components/default/DefaultView';
import DashboardListCard from '../components/DashboardListCard';
import DashboardHeader from '../components/DashboardHeader';
import DashboardGridCard from '../components/DashboardGridCard';
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  useFocusEffect,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const AppHeader = ({
  scene,
  previous,
  navigation,
  searchIconVisible = false,
  item,
  index,
  onPress
}) => {
  const [dashboards, dispatchDashboards] = useReducer(apiStateReducer, {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true,
    isError: false,
  });
  const [gridView, setGridView] = useState(false);

  const toggleGridView = () => {
    setGridView(!gridView);
  };

  const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState([]);

  const setLoading = (value) => {
  const messages = dashboards.data.message.filter((item) => {
      const title = item.dashboardTitle || item.dashboardName;
      return title.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase());
    });
    setFiltered(messages);
    console.log(filtered);
  };

  const dropShadowStyle = styles.dropShadow;
  const toggleSearchVisibility = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Search');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    CognitensorEndpoints.getDashboardList({
      dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
    });
    CognitensorEndpoints.getList({
      dispatchReducer: dispatchDashboards,
    });
  },[]);

  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <View style={styles.headerLeftIcon}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.pop}>
          {previous ? (
            <MaterialIcons
              name="chevron-left"
              size={24}
              style={styles.visible}
            />
          ) : (
            <MaterialIcons
              name="chevron-left"
              size={24}
              style={styles.invisible}
            />
            )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      {filtered.map(item => (
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>
        {item.dashboardTitle}
      </Text>
    ))}
      <View style={styles.headerRightIconContainer}>
        {searchIconVisible ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.headerRightIcon, dropShadowStyle]}
            onPress={toggleSearchVisibility}>
            <MaterialIcons name="search" size={24} style={styles.visible} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <View style={styles.invisible} />
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  </>
  );
};
```

What would be the correct way to call the function ('setLoading()')?

Comment: What does the console / dev tools say?

Comment: `setLoading` takes one parameter, you're calling it without a parameter

Comment: @ritaj that wouldn't cause the function not to be called. https://jsfiddle.net/uq52whfb/

Comment: What does `setLoading` actually do?

Comment: @Vlad setLoading takes a boolean variable to set the state. When the state is changed, the render is then updated. For example, while loading, you could setLoading(true). After some async functions, you could setLoading(false) to re-render the view and show the new data.